# Dropdown menu is outside of window area - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

The dropdown menu of Bootstrap Twitter is open on bottom and not appear because is outside of window area. I need show on top. Have a property to force appear on top?

Comment: Maybe using `style.position:'absolute'` and `top:0`

Comment: Can you post your code in a jsfiddle or link to your site?

Comment: Hello Billy! See on jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/marloscarmo/2FeRT/

Answer (score 5):

To get the menu to go up the way you just add the .dropup class on to the div with the .btn-group class.

```
<div class="btn-group dropup">
  <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Action
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>aaaaa</li>
      <li>aaaaa</li>
      <li>aaaaa</li>
      <li>aaaaa</li>
      <li>aaaaa</li>
      <li>aaaaa</li>
      <li>aaaaa</li>
      <li>aaaaa</li>
      <li>aaaaa</li>
      <li>aaaaa</li>
      <li>aaaaa</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Full info here:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns

Comment: I read the documentation, but this detail went unnoticed. Thanks!

Comment: the documentation link is broken